# JQuery 'Choppy' animation - simple test case

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-position

Here's a simple test case for animating a Div using absolute positioning and jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function slide(){
            $('#box').animate({'left': 0},3000);
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="slide()">slide</button>
    <div id="box" style="position: absolute; width: 120px; height: 100px; background: #ff0000; left: 500px"></div>
</body>
```

In Firefox 4 (on mac) the animation 'tears' and is very stuttery. In Safari and Chrome it is better, but still has visible juddering.

Having simplified the problem down to the above test case, I'm not really sure where to go next. Is this a jQuery bug? Am I missing something with the absolute positioning that would cause the browser to redraw loads? Would be incredibly grateful if some people could try the code above and have a think.... even if its only to reassure me that I'm not going mad :)

Comment: I knocked up this quick jsFiddle that replicates the functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/3THuW/ I can't seem to get it to tear in either FF4 or Chrome 10 on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, was doing the same.. Chrome 10 on OS X renders it OK. Maybe a tiny bit juddery, but nothing out of the ordinary for js.

Comment: I always find FF on Mac chokes on animations. Seems to run smoothly on other browsers, but even the simplest cross-fades are jumpy / stuttery on a Mac.

Comment: same here. animation hangs at least once for a short time (ff/mac)

Answer (score 1):

why using `onclick="slide()"` if u want to slide on click of button then do following

#### CSS

```
#box {
       position: absolute;
       width: 120px;
       height: 100px;
       background: #ff0000;
       left: 500px;
}
```

#### HTML ( assign some id )

```
<button id="slide">slide</button>
<div id="box">whetever</div>
```

### jQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('button#slide').click(function(){
            $('#box').animate({'left': 0},3000);
        });
});   
</script>
```

### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EFBbZ/)

---

### UPDATE ( from [jQuery1.6](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/))

> Smoother Animations
>
> Additionally jQuery is now using the
>   new requestAnimationFrame method
>   provided by browsers to make our
>   animations even smoother. We can use
>   this functionality to avoid calling
>   timers and instead depend upon the
>   browser to provide the best possible
>   animation experience.

```
.promise()
```

Just like `$.ajax()` before it, `$.animate()` gets **“deferred”**. jQuery objects can now return a Promise to observe when all animations on a collection have completed:

```
$(".elements").fadeOut();

$.when( $(".elements") ).done(function( elements ) {
    // all elements faded out
});
```

**HAPPY TO HELP :)**

Comment: Sorry but i really didn't get what means by `stuttery`??

Comment: This is just optimized code... i think he have to change the time period from `3000`to `slow` or `fast`

Comment: I just chucked the button in there as a simple way to kick off the animation (and to make sure that the problem was not being caused by some timers I was using to kick off the animation in the full set of code which I then simplified down to the test case).